# Does this pattern reduce to a simple formula, possibly a recursive one?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I've brute-force written out up to `N=4` and I'm wondering if it's possible to express this in a simple recursive formula.

```
f({A}) = 1 * (A) 
       = A

f({A,B}) = 2 * (A + B) + 1 * (A) + 1 * (B) 
         = 3A + 3B

f({A,B,C}) = 3*(A+B+C)+2*(A+B)+2*(B+C)+2*(A)+1*(B)+2*(C)
           = 7A + 8B + 7C

f({A,B,C,D}) = 4*(A+B+C+D)+3*(A+B+C)+3*(B+C+D)+4*(A+B)+2*(B+C)+4*(C+D)+4*(A)+2*(B)+2*(C)+4*(C)
             = 15A + 18B + 18C + 15D
```

I'm actually not sure whether it's more important to look at them grouped by contiguous subsections of the original array (as in the first part of each of my equals above) or by the individual numbers.

And I see that if I'm grouping them by individual numbers, the first and last is `2^n - 1` where `n` is the size of the array.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the pattern is you are following.  For f({A,B,C,D}), why don't you have a term for 3*(A+B+D)?  Are you excluding terms where you "skip" a letter?

Comment: @Carser Yes, that's why I said "contiguous subsections"

Comment: "contiguous subsections" appears above, but it isn't clear that it was intended as part of your pattern.  Anyway, you are multiplying each of these subsections by their length, right?  I'm just asking for clarifications so we can avoid having to make assumptions.

Comment: the rules are not that clear, for instance in the third case in this part `2*(A)+1*(B)+2*(C)` why only B multiplying by 1?? in the last one why there is no individual D? and what are the rules for each coefficient for each "contiguous subsection"?

Answer (score 1):

I think I start to see a pattern here, looking at the data

```
F([A])       =   A
F([A,B])     =  3A +  3B
F([A,B,C])   =  7A +  8B +  7C
F([A,B,C,D]) = 15A + 18B + 18C + 15D
```

grouping them by common factors and leaving outside the extras

```
F([A])       =   A
F([A,B])     =  3(A+B)
F([A,B,C])   =  7(A + B + C) + B
F([A,B,C,D]) = 15(A + B + C + D) + 3(B+C)
```

them the pattern that arise is a follow

```
F([]) = 0
F(X)  = (2^n-1)*sum(X) + F(center(X))
```

where `n` is the size of X, `sum(X)` is the summation over the element in X and `center(X)` is a function that drop the first and last element of the given array

with that, then the next one is

```
F([A,B,C,D,E]) = 31(A+B+C+D+E) + F([B,C,D])
               = 31(A+B+C+D+E) + 7(B+C+D) + C
               = 31A + 38B + 39C + 38D + 31E
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the pattern, I come up with a slightly different solution to that of Copperfield which is to keep reapplying the center logic until there is no more center, rather than apply it only once:

```
F(x) = (2^n - 1) * sum(x) + F(center(x)) + F(center(center(x)) ....

F({A}) = 1A
F({A,B}) = 3A + 3B
F({A,B,C}) = 7A + 8B + 7C 
F({A,B,C,D}) = 15A + 18B + 18C + 15D
F({A,B,C,D,E}) = 31A + 38B + 40C + 38D + 31E
F({A,B,C,D,E,F}) = 63A + 78B + 84C + 84D + 78E + 63F
```

The results are identical until `F({A,B,C,D,E})` where the C term is one larger than Copperfield's:

```
F({A,B,C,D,E}) = 31(A+B+C+D+E) + F({B,C,D}) + F({C})
               = 31(A+B+C+D+E) + 7(B+C+D) + C + C
               = 31A + 38B + 40C + 38D + 31E
```

and from there the difference increases. Either interpretation can be made from the data supplied, it's up to the OP to supply the next term to see which solution is correct (or that both are wrong.)

Finally, the OP's last equation has what appears to be an error in final term:

```
f({A,B,C,D}) = 4*(A+B+C+D)+3*(A+B+C)+3*(B+C+D)+4*(A+B)+2*(B+C)+4*(C+D)+4*(A)+2*(B)+2*(C)+4*(C)
```

which probably should be:

```
f({A,B,C,D}) = 4*(A+B+C+D)+3*(A+B+C)+3*(B+C+D)+4*(A+B)+2*(B+C)+4*(C+D)+4*(A)+2*(B)+2*(C)+4*(D)
```